# Python Tkinter/GUI Not Updating/Working Correctly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.3

I'm wondering if anyone can give me a quick simple fix for my issue.
I'm trying to make a program (as a gcse mock) that will obtain the position of words in a sentence.

I have the sentence bit working great in the text however I want to go above and beyond to get the highest possible marks so I'm creating it again with a gui!

So far I have the following code and it's not working correctly, it's not updating the 'sentence' variable and I'm looking for a simple way around fixing this Instead of updating.  I get some random number which I'm not sure where it has come from.  Any help will be much appreciated. :)

```
    #MY CODE:
    #GCSE MOCK TASK WITH GUI
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

sentence = ("Default")

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.title("Sentence")
window.geometry("400x300")
#Add custom logo here later on


def findword():
    print ("")


sentencetext = tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter Sentence: ")
sentence = tkinter.Entry(window)
sentencebutton = tkinter.Button(text="Submit")

findword = tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter Word To Find: ")
wordtofind = tkinter.Entry(window)
findwordbutton = tkinter.Button(text="Find!", command = findword)


usersentence = sentence.get()
usersentence = tkinter.Label(window,text=sentence)



shape = Canvas (bg="grey", cursor="arrow", width="400", height="8")
shape2 = Canvas (bg="grey", cursor="arrow", width="400", height="8")


#Packing & Ordering Modules
sentencetext.pack()
sentence.pack()
sentencebutton.pack()

shape.pack()


findword.pack()
wordtofind.pack()
findwordbutton.pack()
usersentence.pack()

shape2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have just edited your post to fix a few Grammar issues and I broke it up for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your sentence's 'submit' button doesn't actually have a command bound, and the two 'sentence' references are likely to conflict: 
`sentencebutton = tkinter.Button(text="Submit")` 
`sentence = ("Default")` 
`sentence = tkinter.Entry(window)`

I can see that what you've tried to do is set it so that the variable sentence changes from "Default" to whatever one enters in the Entry window - this will not work, all you've done is set it so that sentence *becomes* the entry widget itself, not whatever is entered.

I would recommend creating a function called something like 'update_sentence', and rename your initial 'sentence' variable to distinguish it from the label: 
`var_sentence = "default"`

`def update_sentence:
    var_sentence = sentence.get()`

And then change your button so it has a command, like so: 
`sentencebutton = tkinter.Button(text="Submit", command = update_sentence)`

Hope this helps!